# apt-get configured to use proxy with some sources but not others

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

Can `apt-get` be configured to use a proxy with some sources but not with other sources?

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 trusty server on an AWS EC2 instance. It needs to use a proxy to get to http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.ubuntu (`deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main`), but i need to use a local repository for Cloudera software configued in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (`deb /cm5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cm/ trusty-cm5 contrib`).

I'm new to Ubuntu and `apt-get`. With RHEL and `yum`, you could configure or not configure a proxy on an individual repository basis. Is it possible to do the same with `apt-get`?

Comment: Apt-get can use proxies on an protocol and a hostname basis. Why haven't you added a `file:///` protocol to that source?